# nodejs HTTP Digest Authentication not working

Tags: node.js, https, digest, digest-authentication

I've been digging deep into stack overflow but haven't been able to solve my problem. I'm trying to access an API that uses digest but have had no success, and my co-workers haven't been able to pin down the problem either. I've hit a wall and have come to Stack Overflow to ask my question.

Here is my authentication code:

```
var https = require("https"),
    crypto = require('crypto'),
    _ = require('underscore');

var options = {
    host: 'api.example.com',
    port: 80,
    path: '/path/to/uri/',
    method: 'GET',
    accept: 'application/json',
    acceptEncoding: 'gzip, deflate',
    connection: 'keep-alive',
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    requestCert: true,
    agent: false
};

var username = 'username',
    password = 'httppassword';

var req = https.get(options, function(res) {

    res.setEncoding('utf-8');

    console.log(res.url);
    console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
    console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));

    var data = "";

    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        data = data + chunk;
    });

    res.on('end', function(){

        console.log(data);
        var challengeParams = parseDigest(res.headers['www-authenticate']);
        console.log(challengeParams);
        var ha1 = crypto.createHash('md5').update(username + ':' + challengeParams.realm + ':' + password).digest('hex');
        var ha2 = crypto.createHash('md5').update('GET:' + options.path).digest('hex');
        var response = crypto.createHash('md5').update(ha1 + ':' + challengeParams.nonce + ':1::auth:' + ha2).digest('hex');
        var authRequestParams = {
            username : username,
            realm : challengeParams.realm,
            nonce : challengeParams.nonce,
            uri : options.path, 
            qop : challengeParams.qop,
            response : response,
            nc : 1,
            cnonce : ''
        };
        options.headers = { 'Authorization' : renderDigest(authRequestParams) };
        console.log(options);
        https.get(options, function(res) {

            console.log("STATUS: " + res.statusCode);
            console.log("HEADERS: "  + JSON.stringify(res.headers));

            res.setEncoding('utf-8');
            var content = '';
            res.on('data', function(chunk) {
                content += chunk;
            }).on('end', function() {
                console.log(content);
            });
        })
    });

});

req.on('error' ,function(err){
    console.log("request");
    console.log(err);
});

req.write('data\n');
req.write('data\n');
req.end();
```

And here is the challenge header sent back by the API

```
{ realm: 'API realm',
  domain: 'https:/api.example.com/',
  qop: 'auth',
  nonce: 'UZ43b0FWC9591pMjy1i6H2okVwgMbDVO6fcgcQ' }
```

EDIT:

I thought it would be helpful for those looking to answer this question for me to provide what I'm actually sending back to the API, so here it is.

```
{ host: 'api.example.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/path/to/uri/',
  method: 'GET',
  accept: 'application/json',
  acceptEncoding: 'gzip, deflate',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
  requestCert: true,
  agent: false,
  headers: { Authorization: 'Digest username="uname", realm="API realm", nonce="UZ43b0FWC9591pMjy1i6H2okVwgMbDVO6fcgcQ", uri="/path/to/uri", qop="auth", response="09c536e22bca031cdbcb289e4065064a", nc="1", cnonce=""' } }
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting? What doesn't work? Do you have HTTP logs to see what the server transactions look like (using something like Charles or Wireshark?)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that! I am getting a 401 error. I'm not suer what's not working which is why I came to SO but something in my authorization code is clearly wrong otherwise I wouldn't be having this problem. No I am not using any HTTP logs. I'll do that now.

Comment: I would log the HTTP transactions and make sure the HTTP request for authorization looks like you're expecting it to look :).  Also what's in the server log for the auth attempt? Are there messages there to explain why it was rejected

Comment: What do you mean server logs? After I respond to the challenge header it sends me back the same exact header with the same exact challenge header (with a different nonce of course). Also, from what I can gather, reading HTTPS traffic is extremely tedious due to use of SSL. Is there a better way to debug my program?

Comment: It's not so bad.  Use Charles, and either use [node-ssl-root-cas](https://github.com/coolaj86/node-ssl-root-cas) or set `process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0"` in the top of your file. And, yes, the server you're speaking with should have a log file which says WHY you received the 401 error message usually.

Answer (score -2):

You can use [http-auth](https://github.com/http-auth/http-auth) module that supports digest authentication

```
// HTTP module
var http = require('http');

// Authentication module.
var auth = require('http-auth');
var digest = auth.digest({
    realm: "Simon Area.",
    file: __dirname + "/../data/users.htdigest" // vivi:anna, sona:testpass
});

// Creating new HTTP server.
http.createServer(digest, function(req, res) {
    res.end("Welcome to private area - " + req.user + "!");
}).listen(1337);
```

Comment: your example shows how to setup a server but it looks like the original question is about making a request

Comment: This is rather misleading, the OP asked for a client not how to setup a server that needs to set up digest auth